# Inverse exponential formula

Tags: logarithms, taylor-expansion, power-series, exponentiation

The exponential formula (or polymer expansion, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_formula), allows one to transform a power series:

$$f(x) = a_1x+\frac{a_2}{2}x^2 + \dots = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!}x^n$$

into the exponential power series:

$$e^{f(x)} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{b_n}{n!}x^n$$

where

$$b_n = B_n(a_1,\dots,a_n)$$

are the [Bell polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials).

Is there a way to go the other way, from the exponential power series, to the original function?

More precisely, suppose that we know the coefficients $b_n$ in the expansion:

$$e^{f(x)} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{b_n}{n!}x^n$$

Can I compute the coefficients $a_n$ of $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!}x^n$, in terms of the $b_n$? In other words, I would like to find the power series of the composition of $\log$ applied to $e^{f(x)}$. Is there a "logarithmic" version of the polymer expansion?

Comment: This formula is [Faa di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula) blindly applied to the series of $f$ and $\exp$. The one you need is the same applied to $f$ and $\ln(1+x)$

Comment: Well, ... $f(x)-1$ and $\ln(1+x)$.

Comment: Yes I understand that. The question is whether there are some computational tricks or combinatorial known objects involved. For instance, in the f -> exp(f) direction, you get Bell polynomial coefficients. Is there a name for the coefficients you get in the exp(f) -> f direction?

Comment: If you look at it, the fact that you can mention the Bell polynomials there is not a significant simplification, but rather a name application. It is like writing $(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}x^k$ and saying "by the way $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ is called *binomial coefficient* and is denoted by $\binom{n}{k}$". Very likely there are names that can be assigned there to the coefficients or parts of them. Perhaps **cumulants** (!?)

Comment: Yes but a name is helpful because, you can then use that name to search literature, find computational packages that implement them (e.g. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BellB.html), which I can use to check the computations I make, etc.

Comment: But yes, *cumulants* is a keyword here! I got that developing a bit more this calculation ...